# Automatically search in all filters with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, cortana

Whenever I hit the windows key to search I only get results from the web. I have to select the appropriate filter to find what I'm looking for. Imo this completely defeats the purpose. On my Mac I can search with spotlight through anything I want.

Is it possible to do the same in windows 10? In other words, when I hit the windows key and I type a name of a song on my PC it will give me that file instead of a websearch.

Comment: My search feature appears to be set to all by default.  I can't find a way to change this setting either.  Maybe Windows needs to refresh its search Index.  Try that?

Comment: @TimmyJim I already tried that and looked through all the settings I could find..